What code can I use to skip the blanks in my cell?
I am new at this but so I need help!  I have created a spreadsheet that I intend to export as a .txt file for uploading to my payroll software.  The code is working great but I can't figure out how to get it skip the blank rows.  I am wanting it to look in column A and if the corresponding cell in column d is blank it needs to skip it and keep going with the loop.  So far nothing is working...
This is my current code.  I don't know what to add or even where.  This is working for everything I need except skipping the blanks.
Dim thisWS As Worksheet
Set thisWS = Sheet1
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim workArea As Range
With thisWS
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set workArea = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(LastRow, 7))
End With

Dim saveFileName As String
saveFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("2024Testing", "text files (*.txt), *.txt")

Open saveFileName For Output As #1

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim lineText As String

For i = 1 To workArea.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To workArea.Columns.Count
        lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & ",") & workArea.Cells(i, j)   
    Next j
    lineText = Left$(lineText, Len(lineText) - 2)
    Print #1, lineText
        
Next i
Close #1

MsgBox "Bonus Import File Created"

End Sub

This is the output... The line with the zero is what I need to be skipped.
BRA29001,BONUS,3201,12132024
BUN29001,BONUS,0,12132024
BYN29001,BONUS,3201,12132024


As quick fix to skip each row where the value in column D is blank, put the lines of the For i... loop in an If statement: If Len(workArea.Cells(i, "D").Value) > 0 Then... End If (assuming there are no error values). Reading from many cells tends to be slow. To increase efficiency, study Tim Williams' answer that reads from an array instead.

Something like this maybe:
Sub TestCsvOutput()
    Const FLD_SEP As String = ","
    
    Dim thisWS As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    Dim workArea As Range, data As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, lineText As String, fld
    
    Set thisWS = Sheet1
    With thisWS
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set workArea = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(LastRow, 7))
    End With
    
    Dim saveFileName As String
    saveFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("2024Testing", "text files (*.txt), *.txt")
    
    Open saveFileName For Output As #1
    
    data = workArea.Value           'get all data as a 2D array (faster)
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)    'loop data rows
        If Len(data(r, 3)) > 0 Then 'any data in Col D on the sheet?
            lineText = ""           'reset line text
            For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2) 'loop columns
                fld = data(r, c)         'get field value
                'wrap field value in quotes if it contains the separator
                If InStr(fld, FLD_SEP) > 0 Then fld = """" & fld & """"
                lineText = lineText & IIf(c > 1, FLD_SEP, "") & fld
            Next c
            Print #1, lineText
        End If 'col D not blank
    Next r
    
    Close #1
    
    MsgBox "Bonus Import File Created"

End Sub

